# Эмулятор андроид и Location

Tags: android

[image: скриншот]
Подскажите в эмуляторе Android Studio 2020.3.1 (Pixel 2)
вообще возможна передача данных из Location в программу?

Comment: Конечно возможна. Почему вы так уверены что проблема именно в эмуляторе, а не в вашем коде?

Comment: Использовал готовое решение из книги Head First. Программирование для Android.

Answer (score 0):

Все норм. Надо было в эмуляторе добавить разрешение на Location.
Там по умолчанию только Google и Crome, добавил свой Odometer и
все заработало.